# MsgSeqNum sequences and different sessions

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

For example I have config for QuickFix/n with two sessions, something like:

```
[DEFAULT]
...

[SESSION]
# Settings for first session
...

[SESSION]
# Settings for second session
...
```

These sessions should have different `MsgSeqNum` sequences i.e. if I send `Logon` message to the first sessions it should have `MsgSeqNum = 1` and `Logon` message send to second session should have `MsgSeqNum = 1` because I send messages to different sessions with different sequences. Am I right?

And yet one related question. Is it possible to have one shared `MsgSeqNum` sequence for different sessions?

**Update**

I am integrating with third-party FIX server. Their support said me what I should send two `Logon` messages (for two sessions) but when QuickFix/n send them I see the following error in response from second `Logon`: `MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 3 but received 1`. Looks like their FIX server has shared/common MsgSeqNum sequence for these sessions (but I am not sure).

So, I want to clarify with this question how QuickFix/n works with `MsgSeqNum` sequences because their poor docs doesn't highlight this moment.

Comment: Each session should have its own counter. I have no reference to drop here to back this up (I'm going off my experience on this). Regarding the second question: can you give a reason why you would want this?

Comment: @TT. Add section with explanation why I ask this question.

Comment: I am 98% sure that they are not sharing seq numbers across 2 sessions.  That would be insane.  I suspect you have `ResetOnLogon=Y` when it should be `N`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root of problem. Provided configuration looks like:

```
[DEFAULT]
...

[SESSION]
# Settings for first session
ResetOnLogon=Y
...

[SESSION]
# Settings for second session
ResetOnLogon=N
...
```

The first session establish connection, send `Logon` message and reset `MsgSeqNum` but the second session always send `MsgSeqNum=1` because it doesn't reset `MsgSeqNum` and on the client and server side they was different (I suppose this is happened because my other test project increase `MsgSeqNum` up to 3 on server side when I run it before).

So, Grant Birchmeier in comment above was right and `MsgSeqNum` sequences are different for different sessions. The problem was in configuration on client side.